# subsetting rows contain NAs for certain columns

Tags: r, subset, na

I have a dataset that for certain columns (say, "USD.Price/l") in certain rows contain NA (in other columns in these rows there are no NAs), I tried to subset out these rows that contain NA. I have two ways: 1) `` df[df$`USD.Price/l`=="NA",] ``  2) `` df[is.na(df$`USD.Price/l`),] `` While the second way works perfectly but why the first gives the correct size, but all NAs in each row and column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is also that `==` returns `NA` where there are `NA` elements.  Also, `NA` is not `"NA"` quoted

```
v1 <- c(NA, 3, 5, NA)
v1 == "NA"
#[1]    NA FALSE FALSE    NA
```

Or without quotes

```
v1 == NA
#[1] NA NA NA NA
```

The correct way is `is.na` or `complete.cases`

```
complete.cases(v1) # returns TRUE where there are no NA
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is.na(v1) # returns TRUE where there are NAs
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If we check `?`

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA. Missing values can also result when character strings are compared and one is not valid in the current collation locale.